# Azure Service Bus WinForms App - Not Receiving/Displaying Messages

Tags: c#, .net, azure, winforms, azureservicebus

I am trying to display messages to a list box in a WinForms application but it is not working. I am using the most recent Azure namespace, hence using asynchronous methods.
Below is `Program.cs`:

```
namespace App
{
    public class Program
    {
    static ServiceBusClient client;
    static ServiceBusProcessor processor;
    public static List<string> data = new List<string>();
            [STAThread]
            public static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
            {
    
                string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
                 data.Add(body);
                // complete the message. messages is deleted from the subscription. 
                await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
            }
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            public static async Task MainAsync()
            {
                
                client = new ServiceBusClient(_serviceBusConn);
                // create a processor that we can use to process the messages
                processor = client.CreateProcessor(_serviceBustopic, _ServiceBusSubscription, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());
            try
            {
                // add handler to process messages
                processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
                // add handler to process any errors
                processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;
                // start processing 
                   await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
                
            }
            finally
            {

                await processor.DisposeAsync();
                await client.DisposeAsync();
            }
       } 
    }
}
//end of Program.cs
```

And the `Form.cs`:

```
namespace App
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static List<string> AppNames = new List<string>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        public static async Task receiveMessage()
        {
            await Program.MainAsync();
            AppNames = Program.data;
        }
        public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await receiveMessage();
            for (int i = 0; i < AppNames.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("item" + AppNames[i].ToString());
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

There is a console version of this program that is functional, but I cannot seem to get it to display the messages in this Winforms Application. Some debugging showed me that the program was getting into the Main async. method upon the button being clicked, but it was not going into the Message Handler despite messages being sent through the service bus.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using mutable `static` state (fields, instances, etc) - it's going to cause you thread-safety and concurrency issues down the line...

Comment: Also, consider re-arranging your source-code so that functions are listed top-to-bottom in linear execution-order instead of the current (seemingly) unorganized layout which is harder to follow than it needs to be.

Comment: You're calling `ListBox.BeginUpdate()` incorrectly, and you're never calling `EndUpdate()` - that's going to cause problems and might even be the real issue here.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your feedback. I have removed the call to 'ListBox.BeginUpdate()' but there is still no data being displayed and it seems like the program is still not getting into the Message Handler.

Comment: @Dai Post updated to include missing parts

Comment: You shouldn't be using a `List<string>` (maybe bind the ListBox to a `BindingList<string>` that is updated concurrently), but I don't see where you're adding Items to the List and also after `await processor.StartProcessingAsync();` returns, the ServiceBusProcessor is disposed. -- As you mentioned, this looks like a not so thoughtful port of a Console app, which probably has something like `Console.ReadKey()` after `await processor.StartProcessingAsync();` (and you press a key to stop the receiver).

Comment: You should move this code from `Program.cs` to a class handler that initializes the ServiceBusClient, starts the ServiceBusProcessor on demand and stops it when not needed anymore (awaiting `StopProcessingAsync()` and then calling `.DisposeAsync()`). -- Use DataBindings to update the Control that shows the messages.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the feedback. The statement where I was attempting to add the body from the service bus message was lost in the transition of the code to this website. The statement `data.Add(body);` is in the MessageHandler. I was trying to populate the list with some message before I moved on to concurrent updating. The post is now updated.

Comment: All right, but, for testing, add `await Task.Delay(10000);` after `await processor.StartProcessingAsync();`, see whether you get 10 seconds' worth of messages.

Comment: @Jimi I tried that but it did not work. I thought about @Dai comment on the use of `try` and `finally`, and modified the async method to just have what is inside `try` following the client and processor creation (for the sake of testing), and the program displays what is inside the list everytime the button is pressed. The messages repeat of course, but the new ones are shown when the button is pressed.

Comment: @RakeshQ Actually your `try/finally` block looks okay to me (though consider using `await using( ... ) {}`) to ensure that an exception thrown from `processor.DisposeAsync();` won't interfere with `client.DisposeAsync();`

Comment: why you need to call `Program.MainAsync();` on every button click ? only once you need to create a SB client and message receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern that you're using for the Service Bus client and processor isn't going to work in your scenario.

In `MainAsync`, when you call `StartProcessingAsync`, the method will return once the processor has started.  Execution is then going to reach the `finally` block, where the processor and client are disposed.  At that point, the processor is not running and, therefore, is not receiving messages.

Each time `button1_Click` runs, you're creating a new set of clients, establishing a new connection to Azure, and then immediately throwing them away.

The processor is intended to be a long-lived type that runs continuously in the background, calling back into your code as messages are available.  Likewise, the client is intended to be used as a singleton for the lifetime of your application.  I'd suggest reading through the [Service Bus "Hello World" sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample01_HelloWorld.md), which would help to explain some of the types and recommended patterns for use.

Comment: After getting rid of the `try` `finally` block and using a different structure to modify the client and processor, the program was able to receive messages.